# How are member instances in C++ constructed?

Tags: c++

I have a class called `A`.

It has an instance or `B`:

```
public:
    B inst;
```

`B`'s constructor is like `B::B(int, int)`.

When creating the `A` class's constructor `A::A() { }`, it gives me the following error:

> No matching function for call to B::B()

when I haven't created or mentioned any B in `A`'s constructor. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Constructing `A` requires all of `A`'s data members to be constructed. In this case, `B` must be default-constructed as you did not provide a member initialization list. As `B` defines a non-default constructor, generation of its implicit default constructor is suppressed - that's why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

When class `A` contains an instance of class `B`, constructing an instance of `A` also requires construction of the contained instance of `B`.

If no constructor of `B` is listed in the initialiser of class `A`, the default is to invoke a constructor of `B` that accepts no arguments.  For example

```
 class A
 {
     public:
      A::A() {};

     private:

       B b;
 };
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
 class A
 {
     public:
      A::A() : b() {};

     private:

       B b;
 };
```

This involves a constructor of `B` with no arguments.   If no such constructor exists, the result is a diagnostic (error message).   Since you have declared/defined a constructor with arguments, a constructor for `B` with no arguments is not implicitly generated.